Where does Edge store its session recovery site list?
Microsoft Edge web browser crashed while I had hundreds of tabs opened.
Now, I want to know where Edge saves those cached pages, or the list of opened pages, where it generates the list to populate the page "Microsoft Edge closed unexpectedly" that comes up after a crash.
I've tried using a disk restore tool, but I don't know where the list of pages is stored so I don't know where to look with that tool.

Are you saying that Edge did not show you the recovery page when you reopened the browser? Edge has a "Recent Tabs" section in the History panel. Have you looked at that? Edge, like other chromium-based browsers, doesn't necessary store the cache in "regular" files like Internet Explorer did, and so even knowing the location where these files may exist will not necessarily help. Edge's profile folder, where all of your browser settings and cache are stored, is C:\Users<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data

Thank you, @music2myear , for trying to  help me .
There is nothing shown at the Recent Tabs, I've double checked that. Perhaps because it has reopened twice. During the first time of its reopen, it crashed unexpectedly. So I was looking for any file that would helps me. Thank you for giving me the cache destination, will try to have a look.
